# Property (T) and Number Theory?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

Pardon the wild question, but

> Are there any known connections between [Kazhdan's property (T)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%27s_property_%28T%29) and number theory, or number theoretic consequences of property (T)?

Edit: To clarify, I'd like to know if there are consequences of property (T) in modern number theory that are significant to number theorists, and in what way are they significant (I'm not a number theorist, and so mostly am looking for enrichment on how thing fit together!)

Thanks, in advance, for any thoughts or references!

Comment: Inasmuch as Kazhdan's property is related to expander graphs, a connection with number theory is given via Ramanujan graphs and cryptography.

Answer (score 5):

At least as a place-holder answer: in the last few years several people have proven subconvexity bounds on $L$-functions by using Ratner's Lemma from the ergodic theory of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ and such... which has some relation to property $(T)$, in my limited understanding of these things. E.g., Michel-Venkatesh' paper on subconvexity for $GL(2)$ is an example of such a viewpoint.

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Property $T$ for a real group implies vanishing of the $1$st Betti number for its arithmetic subgroups.  Do you consider this number theory?  (I do.)

Comment: The connection with arithmetic groups is kind of the motivation for this question. What I'd like to know is if this information or other information following from Property (T), plays a role in modern number theory in any significant or central way.

Comment: @Jon: Dear Jon, Yes, cohomology of arithmetic groups plays a key role in modern number theory, and vanishing results are important.  Regards,

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference where I can learn more about such things?